# UV Mapping in Autodesk Maya 2011 goes wrong

Tags: textures, maya

I'm always struggling with UV mapping, I'm still a student though. When I am creating a UV map the texture on the object always seems to be very low resolution... does anybody know  a very good tutorial, or can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: If you mean the resolution you see in the interactive viewport, Maya uses the full resolution when you render the scene. I think there are options to adjust the interactive view however.

Comment: Thanks, I still have a lot of problems unfolding correctly.. :( I hope texturing is hard in fact..

Answer (score 1):

UV mapping is one of the trickier things to get used to. It can actually be pretty fun. I always think of it as solving a puzzle you made yourself. Its also an art in itself and making good UV maps only comes with a lot of practice (but reading stuff on the net helps too!)

Texel density, or the amount of texture space you give different parts of your mesh, plays a big part in avoiding fuzzy elements. Read over [this thread](http://www.polycount.com/forum/showthread.php?t=35204) to get a good grip.

Pretty much, your texture corresponds to the 0-1 square of the UV editor. If you are not using a tiling texture, you need to make sure that all your UV 'islands' fit within this space, and are given enough room relative to how big the area is on the actual 3d mesh.

The bigger the mesh area, the bigger the UV island needs to be to avoid resolution issues.

To address other causes of fuzziness:
 - Make sure your texture is of a high enough resolution. 
 - Try to keep visible areas to a similar texel density. 
 - Save texture space by making sure obscure parts of the mesh have smaller UV islands. 
 - Use a texture format that doesn't use hardcore compression (I like to use TGAs)

Hope some of that helps!